# implicit map shadows other implicits

Tags: scala, dictionary, implicit

If I write:

```
class T
implicit val m = Map[String, Map[T, Int]]()
"123"(0)
```

it complains with:

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Int(0)
  required: T
          "123"(0)
```

But it should return '1'. All that I understand is that not only m is implicit, but also m.apply. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map[A,B]` is a `A => B`, so scala converts your string to your `Map[T, Int]`.

This has been complained about on the MLs.

Comment: ah ok so you mean it would be the same as if I defined `implicit def m(s: String): Map[T, Int] = ???`

Comment: @MikaëlMayer except implicit val does not require the feature import. IIRC.